# Oracle multi-row 'insert if not exists' from select joined with table literal

Tags: sql, oracle, insert, multirow

Suppose I have the following table structure:

```
a (a_id number primary key, a_code varchar unique not null)
b (b_id number primary key, a_id number foreign key references a(a_id), b_value varchar
```

I need to insert on table `b` a couple hundred pairs of `(a_id, b_value)` if they do not already exist, and the information I have is `(a_code, b_value)`. I'm coming from a Postgres background where doing this would be trivial, but I'm having trouble finding a way of pulling it off in Oracle without resorting to creating and subsequently dropping a materialized view, or doing one insert per row.

This was the least ugly solution I was able to come up with:

```
insert /*+ IGNORE_ROW_ON_DUPKEY_INDEX(b_value, iun_b_value) */
into b (b_id, a_id, b_value)
select b_id.nextval, a_id, b_value
from a
inner join

(select 'code1' a_code, 'value1' b_value from dual union all
select 'code2' a_code, 'value2' b_value from dual union all
select 'code3' a_code, 'value3' b_value from dual union all
select 'code4' a_code, 'value4' b_value from dual) new

on a.a_code = new.b_value
```

But I was told I can't use that semantic hint for handling duplicate rows on production, so I tried this:

```
merge into b using
  (select a_id, b_value
  from a inner join 

  (select 'code1' a_code, 'value1' b_value from dual union all
  select 'code2' a_code, 'value2' b_value from dual union all
  select 'code3' a_code, 'value3' b_value from dual union all
  select 'code4' a_code, 'value4' b_value from dual) new

  new on a.a_code = new.a_code) insert_codes

on (insert_codes.a_code = b.a_code and insert_codes.b_value = b.b_value)
when not matched then
  insert (b.b_id, b.a_id, b.b_value)
  values (b_id.nextval, insert_codes.a_id, 1, insert_codes.b_value)
```

But I get the same `"ORA-00980: synonym translation is no longer valid"` error I was getting when I was referencing an alias in a subselect while trying to solve this using a `where not exists` clause.

Is there any way to do it without materialized views or multiple inserts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at my simplified example made me realize what was wrong. The `on` clause was

```
on (insert_codes.a_code = b.a_code and insert_codes.b_value = b.b_value)
```

but it should be

```
on (insert_codes.a_id = b.a_id and insert_codes.b_value = b.b_value)
```

So this works:

```
merge into b using
  (select a_id, b_value
  from a inner join 

  (select 'code1' a_code, 'value1' b_value from dual union all
  select 'code2' a_code, 'value2' b_value from dual union all
  select 'code3' a_code, 'value3' b_value from dual union all
  select 'code4' a_code, 'value4' b_value from dual) new

  new on a.a_code = new.a_code) insert_codes

on (insert_codes.a_id = b.a_id and insert_codes.b_value = b.b_value)
when not matched then
  insert (b.b_id, b.a_id, b.b_value)
  values (b_id.nextval, insert_codes.a_id, 1, insert_codes.b_value)
```

Posting here in case someone else has trouble pulling off the same kind of insert in the future.

Comment: The question doesn't make sense. The solution makes perfect sense but is inconsistent with your question. In the question you said the information you have is `(a_code, b_value)`. This doesn't make sense, because it doesn't tell you to which `a_id` that should be attached. In the solution, however, in the "corrected" `on` clause, you use `insert_codes.a_id`. So, do you in fact have `(a_id, b_value)` and not `(a_code, b_value)` as inputs? That would answer all the questions. As it is, you gave the correct solution to the wrong problem.

Comment: I forgot to mention there is a 1 to 1 relation between `a_id` and `a_code`, my bad (I'll edit the question to reflect that). `a_code` is also unique and not null, just not the primary key. My literals, aliased as `new`, _are_ `(a_code, b_value)` pairs. I'm joining that with table `a` in order to get the corresponding `a_id` for each `a_code` literal and so obtain the `(a_id, b_value)` pairs I want to insert, and aliasing _that_ as `insert_codes`.  So the merge's `on` clause was failing because I was referencing a field that didn't make sense and didn't even exist in `insert_codes`.